# Which header file to include for the use of gethostbyname_r() function

Tags: c, linux, networking

I am using `gethostbyname_r()` function in my code, I am getting following error while compiling.

gethostname.cpp:17: error: 'gethostbyname_r' was not declared in this scope

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/file.h>
int main()
{
  struct hostent hostbuf;
 struct hostent *hp = NULL;
 char* hostent_buff;
 int herr = 0;
 int hres = 0;

 hres = gethostbyname_r("domain name", &hostbuf,
 hostent_buff, 1024, &hp, &herr);

 if (NULL == hp)
 {
 return -1;
 }

  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me?
And Can I use same same function gethostbyname_r() on Linux and Solaris?

Comment: Just curious, why's your file named `gethostname.cpp`? what compiler you are using, please?

Comment: Also note, `gethostbyname_r` is GNU Extension, not a standard `C` library function.

Comment: Also note, modern code should use `getnameinfo` and `getaddrinfo` instead

Comment: Is there more to the error message?  Perhaps a signature mismatch?  You have the correct #includes according to the man pages I have.

Comment: @Sourav gethostname.c is also not working getting ld: Unsatisfied symbol "gethostbyname_r" in file /var/tmp//ccLwNIet.o

Comment: yes Joe I have includes proper header files as per man page.

Comment: How are you compiling this ?

Comment: @Leiaz by gcc gethostname.cpp

Comment: try including `#include <features.h>` and check

Comment: No Santosh its not working

Comment: I'm not very sure, but check your `glibc` version by running `ldd --version`. If it is less than 2.0 version, its less likely that `gethostbyname_r()` will be present. I think `gethostbyname_r()` is an available on glibc2.0 and later.

Comment: glibc version is 2.5

Comment: gethostbyname() is working instead of gethostbyname_r() in same code.

Comment: Check your [Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname_r).

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't know which macro I have to define for feature_test_macros.

Comment: @Alnitak, Can you pls tell me how to convert struct addrinfo return by getaddrinfo() to struct hostent?

Comment: @dcds you don't, you use the `struct addrinfo` directly.

Comment: @Alnitak, No I need data in struct hostent only.

Comment: @Alnitak, coz whoever will be calling my code is expecting me to return struct hostent only, and they are not going to change their implementation. So only I have to bear this.

Comment: so keep using `gethostbyname_r()`, then.

Comment: That is not Thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <netdb.h>
```

or

```
#define _SVID_SOURCE
#include <netdb.h>
```

Longer answer:

This is not a POSIX function. You're asking about Linux. According to the man-page, you want

```
#include <netdb.h>
```

and the following feature test macros:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see `feature_test_macros(7)`):
>
> ```
>   gethostbyname2(), gethostent_r(), gethostbyaddr_r(), gethostbyname_r(),
>    gethostbyname2_r():
>        _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE
> ```

Confirming this on my system, `/usr/include/netdb.h` contains:

```
extern int gethostbyname_r (const char *__restrict __name,
                            struct hostent *__restrict __result_buf,
                            char *__restrict __buf, size_t __buflen,
                            struct hostent **__restrict __result,
                            int *__restrict __h_errnop);
```

However, this is conditional on

```
#ifdef __USE_MISC
```

which probably implies you have defined neither `_BSD_SOURCE` nor `_SVID_SOURCE` which is necessary to get the define.

From `features.h`:

```
 __USE_MISC           Define things common to BSD and System V Unix.
```

Then:

```
#if defined _BSD_SOURCE || defined _SVID_SOURCE
# define __USE_MISC     1
#endif
```

Comment: Can I use same same function gethostbyname_r() on both Linux and Solaris?.